# Passing arguments to a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass arguments to a remote machine using the attached script. But it is throwing exception saying: "cannot index into null array". Where am i going wrong ?

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)][ValidateNotNull()]$server = $(throw "Please provide Environment name. Ex: cyclone,jwoww or joker"),
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, position = 1)][string]$logType = $(throw "Please provide type of log you want"),
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, position = 2)][string]$howMany = $(throw "Please provide number of log rows you want")
)

invoke-command -computername $server -credential abc\def{

Get-EventLog -logname $arg[0] -newest $arg[1] | Out-File c:\EventLogs.txt 

} -argumentlist $logType,$howMany
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `Param` block to the [Invoke-Command](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135225) cmdlet and use the parameter names instead of `$arg[0]` and `$arg[1]`

```
invoke-command -computername $server -credential abc\def{
    Param($logType, $howMany)

Get-EventLog -logname $logType -newest $howMany | Out-File c:\EventLogs.txt 

} -argumentlist $logType,$howMany
```

Comment: Tried this already. It doesnt ask for values when inside script block executes and throws an exception asking for values.

Comment: Just add a write-host before the `Invoke-Command` call and dump your parameters, like: `Write-Host $server; Write-Host $logType; Write-Host $howMany` to esnure the parameters are passed successfully to your script.

Comment: parameters are not passing into the script block. If i ask user to enter params inside script block, it doesnt ask for params and just throws the error that a value should be entered

Comment: You have to remove all the `throw`s within your parameter definition: `= $(throw "Please provide type of log you want")`

Comment: error : cannot bind argument to parameter 'LogName' because it is an empty string

Comment: As the error tells you, `LogName` is empty. If you want further help, you need to also show us how you are invoking the script.

Comment: This is the complete code. Invoke-command executes the script on the mentioned computer. Nothing more to this script. Anyway, logType value is set to desired  once script is run, but it is not going into the script block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113077/discussion-between-jisaak-and-ritesh-thakur).